# Transfer revoked

Tags: management

Can my transfer (that has been accepted to move to another department) be revoked, if the accepting office decide to, due to previous issues over 4 years ago where I had to request a facilitated transfer to move out?

Comment: You provided no details about the issues, so I am not sure that any "yes" or "no" answer we provide you is going to be of any value to you. Voting to close for that reason.

Comment: Hi Jane, thanks for your post. I'd like to add that even with greater detail added in, this sounds like it is a tricky situation that will depend on your contract, work policies, and laws in your country. The best place to take this is probably HR if you have it, a senior manager you trust, a union representative, or a lawyer.

Answer (score 4):

> Can my transfer (that has been accepted to move to another department)
>   be revoked, if the accepting office decide to, due to previous issues
>   over 4 years ago where I had to request a facilitated transfer to move
>   out?

Unless you have a contract or union rules specifically prohibiting such a revocation, then **Yes - a company can revoke a transfer for any reason it chooses**.

IF you have incurred expenses after the transfer was granted but before it was revoked, then it would be reasonable for you to ask for reimbursement.